# Using Spectron to "mock" Electron when testing with Jest

Tags: jestjs, electron, spectron

I'm testing library code for an Electron app with Jest. Jest does weird things to `require`, which is interfering with that Electron needs to do... I think.

Spectron is meant to allow you to access the various Electron bits from within a test framework, by allowing you to create an Electron app via library calls.

Ultimately, I need to be able to mock `require('electron')` with *some* real stuff from Electron (like the creation of browser windows), mostly so that various library bits can work as intended.

Here's what it looks like *should* work:

in package.json:

```
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^electron$": "<rootDir>/test/mocks/electron.js"
    }
  }
```

test/mocks/electron.js:

```
const Path = require("path")
const Application = require('spectron').Application
const electronPath = Path.join(__dirname, "../../node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron")
const app = new Application({ path: electronPath })
module.exports = app.electron
```

According to the [docs](https://github.com/electron-userland/spectron#electron), `app.electron` should give access to the same things as `require('electron')` does under normal operation.

Some test:

```
const { BrowserWindow } = require("electron")
test("some test", () => {
  const window = new BrowserWindow()
  // ...
})
```

However, this fails because `app.electron` is undefined, although `App` itself is defined:

```
    console.log test/mocks/electron.js:58
  <ref *1> Application {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 9515,
    quitTimeout: 1000,
    startTimeout: 5000,
    waitTimeout: 5000,
    connectionRetryCount: 10,
    connectionRetryTimeout: 30000,
    nodePath: '~/.nvm/versions/node/v13.0.1/bin/node',
    path: '~/electron-hello-world/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron',
    args: [],
    chromeDriverArgs: [],
    env: {},
    workingDirectory: '~/electron-hello-world',
    debuggerAddress: undefined,
    chromeDriverLogPath: undefined,
    webdriverLogPath: undefined,
    webdriverOptions: {},
    requireName: 'require',
    api: Api { app: [Circular *1], requireName: 'require' },
    transferPromiseness: [Function (anonymous)]
  }
```

Not really sure where to go from here.  Looking for any solutions

Comment: any update on this? I'm having a similar problem.

Comment: Uhh, I think I didn't make any progress but I'll check tomorrow.